# f(x).subs() substitution in sympy (python)

Tags: python, sympy

I defined symbols a and f. I'm expecting to use "a(3).subs(a,f)" to get f(3), but instead I got a(3). What's wrong with it?

```
a, f = symbols('a f')

a(3).subs(a,f)
```

Comment: Please update your code to show how you're trying to access f(3).

Comment: The last line of my code:  a(3).subs(a,f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace` to change the function. Here are some examples.

```
import sympy as sp

f = sp.Function('f')
g = sp.Function('g')
x,y = sp.symbols('x, y')

f(x).replace(f, g)
```

> `g(x)`

```
f(x).replace(f, sp.sin)
```

> `sin(x)`

```
f(x,y).replace(f, lambda *args: sp.exp(-5 * args[0] + args[1] ))
```

> `exp(-5*x + y)`

The [documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.replace) provides an extensive list of additional examples.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `f` as a function and then you replaced it with the return value from `symbols()`.

Comment: Sorry, I see that. But then what? Why I couldn't get f(3)